# OpenVPN with AsusWRT-Merlin

Tags: router, routing, openvpn, asuswrt-merlin

I'm trying to setup my router running the AsusWRT-Merlin firmware as an OpenVPN client. The VPN is a simple static key based one to my root server. The goal is to have all traffic from my local net to be routed through the VPN.

Under VPN -> OpenVPN Client I set up the configuration for connecting to my server using the `local/remote` endpoints of `192.168.42.2/192.168.42.1` and set `Redirect Internet Traffic` to `All Traffic`. The VPN is up and running, but my traffic is not routed through the VPN.

System Log - Routing Table shows the following:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
192.168.42.1    *               255.255.255.255 UH      0   0   0   tun11
100.74.255.254  *               255.255.255.255 UH      0   0   0   WAN
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U       0   0   0   LAN
100.74.192.0    *               255.255.192.0   U       0   0   0   WAN
default         100.74.255.254  0.0.0.0         UG      0   0   0   WAN
```

As you can see the VPN TUN interface is up correctly, but all traffic is still routed through `100.74.255.254` which is my current cable modem IP.

Question is how/where to configure that all local network traffic goes through the VPN?

Screenshots of my settings can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4WrR.jpg

Comment: Your routing table shows that the default route is via WAN and so you have **not** used `--redirect-gateway` in your configs for OpenVPN.